# Provide information from controller back to overall layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is a newbie MVC question from a WebForms developer... I have a stock standard MVC 5 ASP.NET project template.

In my _Layout.cshtml I have:

```
<body>
    <h1>|Some title Goes Here|</h1>        

    @RenderBody()

</body>
```

I want the currently executing Action to be able to set the content for the H1 tag. How do I accomplish that?

As the heading can dynamically change based on the controller and the action being called within the controller by RenderBody() its not as simple as [How To Call Controller from Layout Html.Partial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24375809/how-to-call-controller-from-layout-html-partial) for instance.

Comment: You can use ViewBag - `<h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>` and in the controller `ViewBag.Title = "My Title";`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for that. A simple approach but then I need to remember in each controller to do that VieBag assignment. I am looking for something more "direct" so that you are forced to implement either a method or similair to make this work

Comment: Whether you use ViewBag, or a BaseViewModel property or a Partial, you still need to remember to set the property